# Appendix problem in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{T.F}
some text

\chapter{C.L}
some more text
\end{document}
```

In this, the ToC shows A. T.F
                       B. C.L
But I want,
                       Appendix A. T.F
                       Appendix B. C.L

I went through some questions similar to this on stackexchange, but I couldn't set it right. Please help me.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped- the best way to thank people for their time is to upvote their answers by clicking on the up arrow. Viewing your profile, I see that you have asked a few questions, but have not cast a single vote! Please use the 'up arrow' to do so- it gives people incentive to look at your questions because it gives them 10 reputation points per vote. You can (and should) vote on all answers that are helpful to you. Welcome to the group :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```
\begin{appendices}
Appendix content here
\end{appendices}
```

[image: screenshot]

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{T.F}
some text

\chapter{C.L}
some more text
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Following the comments, you can use

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
```

to make the Appendix appear in upper case.

Comment: Thanks. It works.! There is one more problem though. I want the word 'Appendix' to be all in capital letters in ToC. Also in the thesis, the word appendix should be all capitals.

Comment: @ArunDesiraju glad it helped :) the best way to say thanks is to up vote :) I'll have a look at your follow-up question, but how would I have known about that from the original?

Comment: I know you wouldnt have known. I realized it later, after the previous answer worked

Comment: @ArunDesiraju updated